# How to fire an AlarmManger from date picker?

Tags: android, datepicker, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I'm making a simple TO-DO-List and I'm trying to give my AlarmManager the date which it will fire on. So I'm passing the data to it from a datePicker. And finally I want to show a notification using my Receiver class.
Note:I'm an android beginner and this is my second app.

Here is my datePicker (OnDateListener method)

```
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dPickerListner=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        yearx=year;
        monthx=month +1;
        dayx=dayOfMonth;
        //save in the database
        database=new Database(getBaseContext());
        String subj=WrittenSubj.getText().toString();
        String deta=WrittenDeta.getText().toString();
        String date=dayx+"/"+monthx;
        theTask.setDate(date);
        theTask.setSubject(subj);
        theTask.setDetails(deta);
        Intent alertIntent=new Intent(getBaseContext(),TaskAlert.class);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthx);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayx);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 14);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 55);


        AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager)
                getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),1,alertIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

        database.Insert(theTask);
        Intent BackToMain=new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(BackToMain);
        finish();
        Toast.makeText(TaskDetails.this, "Date saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }


};
```

And this My Receiver class

```
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

  public class TaskAlert extends BroadcastReceiver {
      ArrayList<TheTask> theTasks=new ArrayList<>();
       @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       CreateNotification(context,"Your Task","You have a task","Task");


}
public void CreateNotification(Context context, String msg, String msgText, String msgAlert){
    PendingIntent notifictIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,new Intent(context,MainActivity.class),0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
            .setContentTitle(msg)
            .setTicker(msgText)
            .setContentText(msgAlert);
    builder.setContentIntent(notifictIntent);
    builder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1,builder.build());

}}
```

Comment: You should clarify what exactly you need help with here.  What specifically is not working in the code?

Comment: Since it looks like you are passing the `TimePicker` object named `view`, try  `int getHour = view.getHour();` `int getMinute = view.getMinute();`

Comment: There is notification is showing, I want to know if I can use the Calendar class in the way I used to fire the alarm in specific times

Comment: Can the AlarmManager be fired at specific days of the year without repeating?